# Jenkins plug-in install issues

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use Jenkins first time for automated deployments. Installed Jenkins and can't install plug-ins. I see below errors. Please advise.

Preparation 
Checking internet connectivity
Checking update center connectivity

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json?uctest at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.testConnection(UpdateCenter.java:905) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.checkUpdateCenter(UpdateCenter.java:718) at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$ConnectionCheckJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1079) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

MSBuild Plugin
 Failure -

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/msbuild/1.26/msbuild.hpi
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:821)
```

Comment: Are you able to open http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/ in a browser on the same computer running Jenkins? If not, you might be blocked and need a proxy access...

Comment: I am able to open.

Comment: How is your Jenkins running? Standalone process? Service? Windows? Linux? 401 is unauthorized. Means you got there, but server doesn't like the request... You can `wget http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/msbuild/1.26/msbuild.hpi` and install manually.

Comment: Windows 7 and Service. How to install manually?

Comment: Try to change the user running the service to be the same as the logged in user. It might help.

Comment: For manual installation, see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Byhand

Comment: I see two options under Service - Log On(1. Local System Account 2. This account). Log on as "Local System account" is selected now and when I select "This account" and give my log-in credentials, Jenkins service Stating and stopping automatically. Not sure why.

Comment: Check Jenkins logs or system logs. Are you able to install other plugins?

Comment: I am having same issue with all plug-ins.